# What is the shape of the electric field lines of a pair of newly formed charged particles?

Tags: electric-fields, dipole

I am trying to visualize the field lines of the spontaneous creation of a pair of oppositely charged particles. Initially, I imagined that they would look like those of a dipole with the two charges moving apart with time. But then I realized that there can be no field outside of a sphere of radius $ct$. So what happens with the field lines, do they look curled inside a sphere first until eventually they become closer to those of a dipole once the radius is very large compared to the distance between charges? Because field lines cannot end in empty space right?

Comment: Why do you think that field lines cannot end in empty space?

Comment: I think i read that in many textbooks, but I might be wrong. May be that assumes that the charge has always existed?